# GCloud Use Load Balancer rules to redirect traffic to specific VMs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have two compute engine VMs that server webpages, this is what I'm looking to do:

The client connects to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) - sending them to VM 1 - receiving a webpage from VM1

When the client connects to [www.example.com/?placeholder](http://www.example.com/?placeholder) it directs them to VM 2 - receiving a webpage from VM2

What would I need to look into for this type of network on Google Cloud and can the vm assigned to the query string be updated via gcloudSDK?

[Pretty much this example for AWS but in gcloud.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuVuNYq2yg8&list=WL&index=426)

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able achieve that. You need one [zonal NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs#zonal-neg) (network endpoint group per VM), and then to create a URL map to route the traffic to the corresponding NEG according to a pattern.

You can use the `gcloud compute url-maps ...` to update the routing.

---

the "should" comes from your example. The routing is performed on a query parameter `?placeholder` and I have a doubt on that. I'm sure if it's a full path, but you need to have a try on this case.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go, I'll update here if routing can be done on a query parameter

Comment: Hi is there any update? How did it go?